# Powershell to look at log and send email notification

Tags: powershell

New to scripting. I need help creating a powershell script which will look at a log file and search for a keyword e.g. fail/unsuccessful, and the keyword is present, send an email of the last 50 lines.

I've got parts of the script working, but I am having trouble putting it together.

Looking at log and printing out the line

```
$PATH="C:\tmp\test.log"
Get-Content $PATH -Tail 50 | Where-Object { $_.Contains("fail") }
```

Email to SMTP server sorted and working

```
$From = "test@foobar.com"
$To = "test2@foobar.com"

$Subject = "Failed notification"
$Body = "This is what I want to say"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.foobar.com"
$SMTPPort = "25"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort
```

I know I need an IF statement to compare the content and set if true, send email.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Quick Question: Your current code only looks for the word "fail" in the last 50 lines of the file and ignores the rest. Is that how you want it?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're learning it's probably easier to be explicit if you need to remind yourself what something will return.

```
[string] $PATH="C:\tmp\test.log"
[string[]] $failedRows = Get-Content $PATH -Tail 50 | Where-Object { $_.Contains("fail") }
# Email to SMTP server sorted and working

[string] $From = "test@foobar.com"
[string] $To = "test2@foobar.com"
[string] $Subject = "Failed notification"
[string] $Body = "This is what I want to say"
[string] $SMTPServer = "smtp.foobar.com"
[string] $SMTPPort = "25"
if( $failedRows -and $failedRows.Length -gt 0) {
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort
}
```

Remember powershell is [weakly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). An editor like [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [powershell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) will help as well as you can see suggestions on how to improve your code.

```
$PATH="C:\tmp\test.log"
$failedRows = Get-Content $PATH -Tail 50 | Where-Object { $_.Contains("fail") }
# Email to SMTP server sorted and working

$From = "test@foobar.com"
$To = "test2@foobar.com"
$Subject = "Failed notification"
$Body = "This is what I want to say"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.foobar.com"
$SMTPPort = "25"
if( $failedRows -and $failedRows.Length -gt 0) {
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort
}
```